# Decimal point is removed before update to character variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data in the below format and I want to update a destination table column of type `varchar2` with below values. But the problem is it updates as `.462` instead of `0.462` by using trim with leading `'0'`.

```
source              destination column
-----------------   ------------------
0000004.304300000   4.3043
0000005.504500000   5.5045
0000141.400000000   141.4
0000138.900000000   138.9
0000000.462000000   0.462
0000000.000297000   0.000297
```

Comment: Why, oh why are you storing numbers in `varchar2` data type? Even if the source is not under your control, at least the target should be. Make the destination column a `number` column; if you must show those numbers with a specific format model on your **reports** (there is no other place where you must show numbers as strings, *with a specific format model*), you can do so when you create the reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of `TO_CHAR`ing and `TO_NUMBER`ing with appropriate format mask might do the job. Have a look at the example:

```
SQL> create table test (source varchar2 (20), destination varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test (source)
  2    select '0000004.304300000' from dual union all
  3    select '0000000.462000000' from dual union all
  4    select '0000141.400000000' from dual union all
  5    select '0000033.000000000' from dual;

4 rows created.

SQL> alter session set nls_numeric_characters = '.,';

Session altered.

SQL> update test set
  2    destination = rtrim(to_char(to_number(source), 'fm999990D99999999'), '.');

4 rows updated.

SQL> select * From test;

SOURCE               DESTINATION
-------------------- --------------------
0000004.304300000    4.3043
0000000.462000000    0.462
0000141.400000000    141.4
0000033.000000000    33

SQL>
```

Comment: Note though that this solution will rewrite the string `'33'` as `'33.'` - it is not clear if that's the OP wants (or needs?) Easy fix: wrap within `RTRIM(....., '.')`

Comment: Thank you, @mathguy. Fixed.